# How to select a directory with the highest version?

Tags: find

Let's say I have three directories within my current working directory.  Each one refers to a different version of a library/package.  I would like to return only the directory with the highest version.  For example:

```
program program-1.0 program-2.0
```

The best I have been able to do is just with the `find` command.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "program*" -print
```

But this provides all three directories.  I would like the **full path** of the `program2` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it with `find`, `sort` and `tail`:

```
find "$PWD" -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "program*" | sort -V | tail -1
```

This will also print the path.

Comment: This will fail if you have e.g. "program-1.0" and "program-10.0"

Comment: Change `-n` to `-V` and it'll work if files are named "program-1.0" and "program-10.0"

Answer (score 5):

Newer versions of the GNU `sort` utility have an option to sort based on version number: from `man sort`

```
   -V, --version-sort
          natural sort of (version) numbers within text
```

So you could do

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'program*' | sort -V | tail -1
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer +1

Comment: OP also want the *full path* to the directory. This won't provide that.